# How can CMake's PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION match multiple lines of output?

Tags: regex, cmake

I'd like to add a test via CMake in the following manner:

```
ADD_UNIT_TEST(MyTest)
set_tests_properties(
    MyTest
    PROPERTIES
        PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION
           "This matches the first line\n"
           "This matches the second line"
)
```

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found [this](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2011-January/041859.html) post and modified your example with the code suggested in the post:

- Replaced `\n` with `[\r\n\t ]*`

The following did work successfully with my CMake version 3.5.2:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(RegExMultiLine)

enable_testing()

add_test(
    NAME 
        MyTest 
    COMMAND 
        ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo 
            "Some other line\n"
            "This matches the first line\n"
            "This matches the second line\n"
            "Another line"
)

set_tests_properties(
    MyTest
    PROPERTIES
        PASS_REGULAR_EXPRESSION
           "This matches the first line[\r\n\t ]*This matches the second line"
)
```

Would give:

```
> ctest -C Debug
[...]
    Start 1: MyTest
1/1 Test #1: MyTest ...........................   Passed    0.03 sec
```

Instead of (when using your original code):

```
> ctest -C Debug
[...]
    Start 1: MyTest
1/1 Test #1: MyTest ...........................***Failed  Required regular expression not found.Regex=[This matches the first line
This matches the second line
]  0.03 sec
```

Comment: Hmm, strange. My bad, I think another tool I'm using in my build system is causing my example to fail, not CMake itself.

Comment: @modocache Sorry for any misunderstanding. Your code - as it is provided in your question - did not work in my Windows environment. I assume this being an issue with CRLF on Windows. So the code I have tested (taken from the linked post) does accept any combination of tabs `\t`, white-spaces ` `, carriage return `\r` or line feed characters `\n` between the two strings to be matched (should work on all host platforms). I've updated my answer accordingly.