# ctest does not report failed test when it actually fail

Tags: unit-testing, cmake, googletest, ctest

I have a unit test code, I use google test, and use cmake to add ctest. After compiling my code, I can run either `ctest` or `make test` to check, all the tests passed.

```
Test project /sciclone/home00/hshi/AFQMCLIB/build
      Start  1: mpiTest
1/10 Test  #1: mpiTest ..........................   Passed    0.05 sec
      Start  2: timeTest
2/10 Test  #2: timeTest .........................   Passed    0.07 sec
      Start  3: errorAnalysisTest
3/10 Test  #3: errorAnalysisTest ................   Passed    0.06 sec
     Start  4: randomNumberTest
4/10 Test  #4: randomNumberTest .................   Passed    0.23 sec
     Start  5: tensorTest
5/10 Test  #5: tensorTest .......................   Passed    0.07 sec
     Start  6: fftwTest
6/10 Test  #6: fftwTest .........................   Passed    0.07 sec
     Start  7: mathTest
7/10 Test  #7: mathTest .........................   Passed    0.04 sec
     Start  8: clusterTest
8/10 Test  #8: clusterTest ......................   Passed    0.05 sec
     Start  9: realMaterialHamiltonianTest
9/10 Test  #9: realMaterialHamiltonianTest ......   Passed    0.11 sec
     Start 10: lanczosTest
10/10 Test #10: lanczosTest ......................   Passed    0.05 sec

100% tests passed, 0 tests failed out of 10

Total Test time (real) =   0.80 sec
```

While, if I run the 5th test separately, I get:

```
...
[----------] 6 tests from Tensor_1d_bl_cpu
[ RUN      ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.copyBlas
[       OK ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.copyBlas (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.normBlas
[       OK ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.normBlas (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.scaleBlas
[       OK ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.scaleBlas (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.dotcBlas
/sciclone/home00/hshi/AFQMCLIB/AFQMCLIB/libhao/test_hao/gtest_custom.cpp:19:     Failure
 Expected: expected.real()
 Which is: 146.65745800000002
 To be equal to: actual.real()
 Which is: 0
/sciclone/home00/hshi/AFQMCLIB/AFQMCLIB/libhao/test_hao/gtest_custom.cpp:20: Failure
  Expected: expected.imag()
  Which is: -36.1877
  To be equal to: actual.imag()
  Which is: 0
[  FAILED  ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.dotcBlas (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.axpy_cpu
[       OK ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.axpy_cpu (0 ms)
[ RUN      ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.gemv_cpu
[       OK ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.gemv_cpu (0 ms)
[----------] 6 tests from Tensor_1d_bl_cpu (0 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 100 tests from 9 test cases ran. (280 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 99 tests.
[  FAILED  ] 1 test, listed below:
[  FAILED  ] Tensor_1d_bl_cpu.dotcBlas
```

If I run `ctest --verbose`, I can see the failed information. While, if I run `ctest`, there is no error.

I am using cmake/3.2.3 and google test to write my unit test, all the tests are mpirun:

```
add_test( NAME MyTest COMMAND mpirun -np 4 $<TARGET_FILE:MyTest>)
```

Have you seen similar problem before? Why `ctest` does not show failed error?

Comment: `ctest` checks **exit status** of the test for decide whether test is passed or failed. Exit status `0` correspond to "Passed". Make sure that you test returns non-zero value on fail.

Comment: In your case you would need to let `ctest` check the tests output against a regex (see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035328/how-can-cmakes-pass-regular-expression-match-multiple-lines-of-output)).

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you. I am using google test, I did see see any exit status in google test.